# Updating a View with changing rows

Tags: sql

I know that when you run an update statement on a table, and someone runs another statement (ex: A delete statement), there is a high chance of blockage occurring; but what happens when you run an update on a view, but a row in that view is removed before the update statement affects it? Example:

I have a view called OpenJobs, that when a job is closed (or deleted) it is removed from the view:

```
JobID - Job Title - Open/Closed
-------------------------------
1     - Sales     - Open
2     - Support   - Open
3     - Sales     - Open
```

I have a process that runs this update statement:

```
UPDATE OpenJobs
Set Open/Closed = 'Closed'
Where [Job Title] = 'Sales'
```

While this statement is running, it updates JobID 1 to Closed, but before it can reach JobID 3, the Job is deleted by another process. Does this also cause blockage? Should you only run updates against tables?

Comment: Table or view doesn't matter, same behavior.

Comment: Locking behaviour is highly dependent on the database product. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: first off very bad column naming